# How do you add inset to UILabel (iOS Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift

I am an Android developer learning iOS. How do you add padding (inset) to UILabel in iOS Swift? I have not been successful at finding an easy tutorial on this. Thank you.

Also, how can I add margins to UI elements in Swift? When I try the below, nothing gets updated (upon hitting "add constraint").

[image]

Comment: post your code segment that you tried. then you'll be able to sort it out fast !

Answer (score 41):

This is the code you need to add in Swift 3:

```
class InsetLabel: UILabel {
    let topInset = CGFloat(0)
    let bottomInset = CGFloat(0)
    let leftInset = CGFloat(20)
    let rightInset = CGFloat(20)

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }

    override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
        intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
        return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
    }
}
```

Comment: When you add this subclass to a UIStackView, this sometimes causes the following warning in the console: "This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that exceeds internal limits.  A smaller value will be substituted, but this problem should be fixed. Break on BOOL _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future." So use with care.

Comment: I wish there was a way to do this without subclassing. I'm currently working on a project that is able to style all UILabels in an app using some pre-defined styling, but it doesn't support subclassed UILabels. Maybe that's the solution to my problem...

Answer (score 25):

Probably the best idea is to subclass `UILabel` and override `drawTextInRect:` like this:

```
class InsetLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)))
    }
}
```

**SWIFT 4+**:

```
class InsetLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)))
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Swift. How do I use that? I'm new to Swift and iOS. @Sebyddd

Comment: @andy7586 - I updated the answer. Instead of making the label of class 'UILabel, make it of class 'InsetLabel'. Add this class implementation somewhere in your .swift file.

Comment: One more question, how can i add margin to any UI element? When I try to manually set (see the updated question), nothing gets updated.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how you make use of that class. Could you please provide a step-by-step on how you use that?

Comment: Now the text gets cut off. It gets truncated. @Sebyddd

Comment: @andy7586 that's because he needed to use `intrinsicContentSize`

Comment: super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)))

Answer (score 9):

need add this:

```
class InsetLabel: UILabel {
let topInset = CGFloat(12.0), bottomInset = CGFloat(12.0), leftInset = CGFloat(12.0), rightInset = CGFloat(12.0)

override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
    super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
}

override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    var intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize()
    intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
    intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
    return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution simply using the storyboard.  In the storyboard, create a UIView object whose purpose will be to surround your label in order to give it padding.  Then, also from the storyboard, put your UILabel inside of that view.  Now select the UILabel object and bring up the Add New Constraints popup by clicking the "Pin" icon.  If you want a padding of 5 all the way around the UILabel, click each of the 4 red I-beams in the Add New Constraints popup, and THEN type 5 in each of the 4 boxes adjacent to the I-beams.  If you type 5 first and then click an I-Beam, XCode reverts to whatever value was in the box before you typed 5.  Finally click the Add Constraints button.

In the Add Constraints popup, XCode ignores top, left, right, or bottom constraint values for which you have not clicked the corresponding red I-beam.  This probably answers the second part of your question.

Remember also to setup the constraints of the UIView you added.  If you don't define where it goes in the storyboard (e.g., pinned to the top and left of the main view of the view controller), it will not be assigned a default location, and it may not show up at all when you run your app.

Comment: Best solution by far

Comment: This would work except if you have sizeToFit() on the label. Then the label and view are dependent on each other and do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried with it on Swift 4.2, hopefully, it works for you!

```
@IBDesignable class PaddingLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 7.0
    @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 7.0

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: size.width + leftInset + rightInset,
                      height: size.height + topInset + bottomInset)
    }    
}
```

Or

you can use CocoaPods here https://github.com/levantAJ/PaddingLabel

pod 'PaddingLabel', '1.1'

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to override textRect:forBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:

> Returns the drawing rectangle for the label’s text. Override this
>   method in subclasses that require changes in the label’s bounding
>   rectangle to occur before the system performs other text layout
>   calculations. Use the value in the numberOfLines parameter to limit
>   the height of the returned rectangle to the specified number of lines
>   of text. This method may be called by the system if there was a prior
>   call to the sizeToFit() or sizeThatFits(_:) method. Note that labels
>   in UITableViewCell objects are sized based on cell dimensions, and not
>   on a requested size.

```
public class JPSLabel : UILabel
{
    open var textInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    override public func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect
    {
        var insetBounds = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
        insetBounds.size.width += self.textInsets.left + self.textInsets.right
        insetBounds.size.height += self.textInsets.top + self.textInsets.bottom

        return insetBounds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested below codes to my app, Swift 5.0 +

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    
    var textInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero {
        didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() }
    }
    
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
        let textRect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
        let invertedInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -textInsets.top,
                                          left: -textInsets.left,
                                          bottom: -textInsets.bottom,
                                          right: -textInsets.right)
        return textRect.inset(by: invertedInsets)
    }
    
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: textInsets))
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use it on label, please mention it's usage as well